# Haskell functions and currying

Tags: haskell

I am tryng to learn Haskell and have begun reading a book on it. It seems pretty interesting and want to continue my journey even if it's hard to grasp at first. I have this piece of code and I want to understand why it works.

```hs
names = [("Ian", "Curtis"), ("Bernard", "Summer"), ("Peter", "Hook"), ("Stephen", "Morris")]

compareLastNames name1 name2
  | lastName1 > lastName2 = GT
  | lastName1 < lastName2 = LT
  | otherwise = EQ
  where
    lastName1 = snd name1
    lastName2 = snd name2

main = do
  print (sortBy compareLastNames names)
```

What I don't understand is `compareLastNames` takes two arguments but even if I pass it a list of tuples, it just works. I know haskell curries functions but how does it work. How is it possible for the function to accept a list of tuples and not throw an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currying has nothing to do with this.

In `(sortBy compareLastNames names)` you call function `sortBy` passing two arguments: `compareLastNames` (a function) and `names` (a list of pairs). This does not directly call function `compareLastNames` in any way; in partcular, this function is not passed `names` as an argument -- that would be a type error, as you realized.

The function `compareLastNames` is only called inside the definition of `sortBy`, which will provide it with arguments of the right type (two pairs).

To stress the point, consider this:

```
foo :: (String -> Int) -> Int -> Int
foo g x = x + g "abcde"

myG :: String -> Int
myG = length

test :: Int
test = foo myG 42
```

Here we do not call `myG` with `42`, which is not a string. Instead, we evaluate `test` as:

```
test
= foo myG 42
= 42 + myG "abcde"
= 42 + 5
= 49
```

The key point to understand here is that we pass `myG` as a function value, not the result obtained by applying it to some other value. Passing the unapplied `myG` allows `foo` to choose the argument for `myG`.

Comment: This example is just perfect. Clarifies my query and also clears up my understanding of how expressions like these are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You are *not* passing a list of tuples to `compareLastNames`.

You *are* calling `sortBy` with the two arguments,  `compareLastNames` and `names`.

`sortBy`, in turn, uses `compareLastNames` to compare any pair of elements from `names` as it needs to, as it sorts it, using `compareLastNames` as the comparing predicate.